# How to fill (color) bars in a bar chart a different color within the bar itself up to a certain number?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
groups <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B"),
                                Reels = c(155, 343),
                                Fish = c(41, 221))
groups %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = Reels)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(
    x = "Group",
    y = "Count"
  )
```

I want to fill the bars in this graph up the amount of fish that were caught. So you can see the different color on the graph. I think I would use the `fill` argument but am having trouble getting that value to cut off at 41/155, for example.

Sort of like in https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html section 3.8 where they colors the graph according to diamond clarity.

My goal is two bars - one for A and one for B that are 155 and 343 tall, respectively. I then want to color in up to the amount of Fish (41/155). Any advice? Please let me know if this needs more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with a text label thrown in for good measure:

```r
groups %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = Reels)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Fish), fill = "red") +
  geom_col(fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Fish + 1, label = paste(Fish, Reels, sep = " / ")), vjust = -0.5) +
  labs(
    x = "Group",
    y = "Count"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

r2evans answer is #1 :)
Just for the record, I think `fill` wasn't working in this case because the data was not ggplot-ready?

```
library(tidyverse)
groups <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B"),
                     Reels = c(155, 343),
                     Fish = c(41, 221))
reshape2::melt(groups) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(
    x = "Group",
    y = "Count"
  )
```